# В чем смысл типа char * const* в языке Си?

Tags: c, указатели, const

**`char*`** - указатель на переменную типа char.

**`char* const`** - константный указатель.

**`const char*`** - указатель на константную переменную.

**`const char* const`** - константный указатель на константу.

**`char const*`** - тоже самое, что и **`const char*`**. Автоматически в него преобразуется.

Но про **`char* const*`** компилятор gcc(c99) рассуждает, как об отдельном типе. Тоже самое с **`const char* const*`**. В чем заключается смысл **`*`** после **`const`** вкупе с **`char*`**? Как описать этот тип?

Comment: `char* const*` без const будет  `char**` т.е. это массив на константные строки.

Comment: Такие объявления проще читаются справа налево.

Answer (score 12):

Это такой же **указатель на указатель**, как `char**`, только менять его адрес (того указателя, на который указывает переменная) нельзя.

```
    char* pc1 = (char*)malloc(LENGTH); strcpy(pc1, "Hello");
    char* pc2 = (char*)malloc(LENGTH); strcpy(pc2, "World");

    char* const* ppc1 = &pc1; // OK
    *ppc1 = pc2; // compile-time error

    char** ppc2 = &pc1; // OK
    *ppc2 = pc2; // OK
```

Answer (score 7):

Расшифровывать подобные обозначения (и более суровые, с участием указателей на функции, например) порой сильно помогает ресурс [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/)

> ```
> char* const* x
> ```
>
> declare x as pointer to const pointer to char
>
> *x это указатель на константный указатель на char*
>
> — [ссылка](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char*%20const*%20x)

`x` (`char* const*`) менять можно.
`*x` (`char* const`) менять нельзя.
`**x` (`char`) менять можно.

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из книги [Бена Клеменса "Язык С в XXI веке"](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31083556/) (Глава 8, Ключевое слово const):

Объявления следует читать справа налево. Таким образом:

- `int const` - константное целое;
- `int const *` - (неконстантный) указатель на константное целое;
- `int * const` - константный указатель на (неконстантное) целое;
- `int * const *` - указатель на константный указатель на целое;
- `int const * *` - указатель на указатель на константное целое;
- `int const * const *` - указатель на константный указатель на константное целое.

Как видите, квалификатор `const` всегда относится к тому, что находится слева от него, - как и `*`.

Можно переставить местами имя типа и `const`, то есть `int const` и `const int` - одно и то же (хотя проделать этот фокус с `const` и `*` не удастся). Я предпочитаю форму `int const`, потому что она согласуется с более сложными конструкциями и прави­лом чтения справа налево. Но чаще встречается форма `const int`, быть может, по­тому что её проще произнести на обычном языке (константное целое) или потому что так "всегда делали". Так или иначе, годятся оба варианта.

---

В статье на хабре [Так вы думаете, что знаете Const?](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301332/) пошли ещё дальше и добавили третий квалификатор `const`:

- `int const * const * const` - константный указатель на константный указатель на константное целое.